# How to define upstream and downstream project in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have 3 projects (A, B, C).

The project A has as downstream the project B.

The project B has as upstream the project A and as downstream the project C.

The project C has as upstream the project B.

Now I have to define, in Jenkinsfile, the pipeline that allow to build automatically the projects B and C when the project A finish its build.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you have A->B->C so in the 
JenkinFile of A

**jenkinsFile**

```
stage ('Starting Sub Jobs') {
   build 'JobB'
}
```

Similarly the JenkinsFile of B

**jenkinsFile**

```
stage ('Starting Sub Jobs') {
   build 'JobC'
}
```

So the JenkinsFile remain indepentdent of each other i.e.

If Job B is trigger then Job C will be triggered. But, if Job A is triggered, then Job B will be triggered which will in turn trigger job C.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Not ideal - this means that the upstream job needs to know of all its "users", which inverts the dependency relationship (consider `A` to be a library used by `B` _etc_).  What would be useful would be a declaration in the Jenkinsfile of the downstream job which is read and stored by Jenkins to maintain the tree of dependencies.  Usual caveats apply!